# How to get new version file via the SVN server

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, versioning

What I want to do is to write a program to check the file in SVN server every single day, and if there is a new version file in specific directories, download it.

I can connect to the SVN server but I don't know how to write a program to check if the files are the new version ones or not.

Please give me some suggestion about this issue.

Update:

I'm using windows platform and installed TortoiseSVN. when I use export function of TortoiseSVN, it downloads all the files in the SVN server. What I want is the file in specific directories.

The syntax of update is defined in the manual as:

```
svn update [PATH...]
```

But it didn't specify syntax of PATH. I only want to update the directory remote_directory_A and download to the local directory local_directory_B. How should I do? Like this?

```
svn update remote_directory_A local_directory_B
```

Comment: Why not just `svn update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN does this for you when you do:

```
svn update
```

If there is a newer revision, and you are checked out at the HEAD, then it will update your local copy with the newest revision.